# android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent case NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I do not know why it case NullPointerException, and I can not find the code which it case.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent(PopupWindow.java:1505)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2750)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2710)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2013)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:384)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3975)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

do you have the same Exception?

Comment: please post your code with the popup window..

Comment: My app use popup window everywhere, and i don`t know which it case this     NPE

Comment: i think its not full logcat.. and when you are getting this error

Comment: just follow the activity which popup crash in, and post it, otherwise its hard to help you..